# Como fazer uma busca de arquivos usando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursão

Problema:
Implemente a função `search()`, que aceita como entrada o nome de um arquivo e o caminho de uma pasta, para procurar o arquivo na pasta e em qualquer pasta nela contida, direta ou indiretamente. A função deverá retornar o caminho do arquivo, se for achado; caso contrário, nenhum deverá ser retornado.

Como eu fiz:

```
def search(file,pasta):
    import os

    for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
        #print(root)
        #print(dirs)
        #print(files)
        if file in files:
            print(root)


path = r"test"
file = "fileE.txt"
search(file,path)
```

O programa acima funciona, mas a ideia é fazer "na mão", ou seja, sem usar  `os.walk`, de alguma forma recursiva. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Por favor, corrija a indentação do seu código na pergunta. E por que a ideia é "fazer na mão"? Onde diz isso no problema?

Comment: @Woss Eu gostaria de saber como fazer sem usar o os.walk....

Answer (score 2):

Eu não sou um especialista em criar funções recursivas mas eu dei o meu melhor para conseguir responder sua questão. É possível fazer à mão uma função como o `walk` através de recursividade só que ainda assim eu precisei utilizar algumas funções do módulo `os` para completar essa tarefa.

Abaixo está a função `search()` que verifica todas as pastas e sub-pastas dentro do diretório atual procurando o arquivo desejado:

```
import os

def search(filename, path = os.getcwd()):

    results = os.listdir(path)

    # Verifica se há um arquivo dentro do diretório atual.
    if filename in results:
        yield path

    for found in results:

        # Junta o caminho atual com o nome do arquivo ou diretório achado.
        found = os.path.join(path, found)

        # Verifica se é um diretório. Se ele for, a função "search" 
        # será chamada novamente para fazer uma busca nesta pasta encontrada
        # e depois será retornado através do yield todos os diretórios 
        # possuem o arquivo desejado.

        if os.path.isdir(found):
            for path in search(filename, found):
                if path: yield path
```

Perceba no código acima que ao invés de se utilizar `return` eu utilizei o `yield`. Eu fiz isso para que a função possa continuar a execução do *for loop* e ir verificando os diretórios seguintes ao mesmo tempo que retorna o caminho obtido.

Talvez exista uma outra forma bem melhor que a minha para se criar essa função, mas isso foi o melhor que consegui pensar e criar. Espero ter lhe ajudado.

Comment: @eanExtreme002  Por que yield ?

Comment: Eu expliquei na resposta. Eu utilizei o `yield` para retornar os caminhos sem que o programa terminasse a execução do *for loop*.